# How can I populate a test table in MySQL with one billion rows?

Tags: mysql

I want to do some tests with MySQL indexes and would like to see the effects of the different types of indexes (covering, clustering) on different queries myself by experimenting.

I have a very simple table with 3 cols, a, b, c.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (
    a INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    b INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    c INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);
```

I then created a stored procedure to populate this 1000 times with random values from 1 to 100.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_procedure;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure
(IN loop_amount INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE rand_max INT DEFAULT 99;
    DECLARE a, b, c INT;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    TRUNCATE TABLE test_table;
    WHILE i < loop_amount DO
        SET a = RAND() * rand_max + 1;
        SET b = RAND() * rand_max + 1;
        SET c = RAND() * rand_max + 1;
        INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (a, b, c);
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL test_procedure(1000);
```

I could not run this many times because it became slow after 1000 loops.

I then doubled the table 13 times.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test_procedure;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure
(IN loop_amount INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    WHILE i < loop_amount DO
        INSERT INTO test_table SELECT * FROM test_table;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL test_procedure(13);
```

But now it has around 16 million rows but I can't run this function anymore because it takes like a minute to run it with 1 as parameter, doubling once takes a minute, next doubling takes 2 minutes etc. How can I get to 1 billion faster?

Also the `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_table;` is really slow too. How can I speed this up to confirm table size?

Comment: Make sure you drop any indexes on that table. Recreate them afterwards.

Comment: There are no indexes on the table yet.

Comment: `call test_procedure(10000);` took 1.8 seconds, `call test_procedure(100000);` took 18 seconds, and `call test_procedure(1000000);` took 172 seconds on my 2011 Macbook. It appears to be scaling up linearly, as expected, so 1 billion should take about 1800 seconds. What sort of times are you seeing? I have an SSD so I/O is very fast, that might be a major factor.

Answer (score 0):

```
load data local infile 'c:\a.txt' into table test_table;
```

[SQL] 
load data local infile 'c:\a.txt' into table test_table;
受影响的行: 1000000
时间: 12.177s